# Spring form:select run JavaScript function on creating options

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

How can I execute a JavaScript function if `select` is creating rows/options?

```
<form:select path="field" multiple="false" size="8" cssClass="reg-selectField" onOptionsCreated="runThisJsFunction()">
    <form:options items="${field}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" cssClass="input-select" disabled="false"/>
</form:select>
```

Something like what I've added `onOptionsCreated="runThisJsFunction()"` on the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that we have a particular event which is triggered when options are loaded.You can do the same thing in `document.ready` jQuery function or in JavaScript something like

```
function options_loaded() {
    var e = document.getElementByNames('field')[0];
    if(e.options.length == 0){
        alert("No options loaded");
    } 
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", options_loaded, false);
```

in jQuery

```
  $(function(){
       var optionsCount = $('[name="field"] option').length;
       if (optionsCount == 0){
          alert("No options are loaded"); 
       }
    });
```

Comment: but how can I check if there'll be no options created? this will run `options_loaded()` function too.